# NextJS Image Optimization not working in production on Vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, next.js13

Currently I'm working on a NextJS application. My application will be deployed with multiple domains on Vercel. The application should render images dynamically. All images are rendered correctly in the preview environment on Vercel, but when I deploy the application in the production environment the Response for the optimized image is:
Bad request
INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST

If I request the original (unoptimized) image everything works as expected.
I am using the latest version of NextJS (14.0.4)

I have tried to use multiple different configurations for NextJS (config.nextjs.mjs).
Also I tried requesting different images manually (original and optimized).

My current next.config.mjs looks like this

```
images: {
    dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
    remotePatterns: [
        {
            hostname: 'domain1.example.com',
        },
        {
            hostname: 'domain2.example.com',
        },
    ],
},
```

My image url for example is /api/images/some-image-uuid
To load optimized images I use the NextJS Image component from next/image.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I have my own project deployed on vercel and Nextjs images are working fine. https://www.uabbaltic.lt/en/login The code https://github.com/ArnasDickus/UABBaltic/blob/main/src/app/%5Blng%5D/login/page.tsx Could you provide more details how you optimize image?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have added some additional information. I have already implemented several projects with NextJS where image optimization works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your nextconfig might be lacking. I suggest adding protocol and port as well as other properties if needed. Here's the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#remote-images)

You also might need to add domain in images object. Here's the [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/20138)

```
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "openweathermap.org",
        port: "",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does not seem to work. But I fixed it by adding the domain and protocol to the image source. I don't know if this is intentional or if there is a way to not have to do this.

Comment: @cc_haensel that's good. If that's not too much trouble. You should post your answer with code example.